Dictionaries and functions in Text Based RPG
everyone. I'm trying to learn more about dictionaries and functions by making a Text Based RPG, but I've run into an issue that I just can't seem to figure out on my own. I made a dictionary for the map on the "main" part of the script, it's not inside of anything, as shown below:
the_map = {
    'Town': {'Next room': 'Ruins', 'Rest': 'Fill HP'},
    'Ruins': {'Next room': 'Destroyed Village', 'Previous room': 'Town', 'Enemy': 'Minotaur'},
    'Destroyed Village': {'Next room': 'Forbidden Forest', 'Previous room': 'The Ruins', 'Enemy': 'Giant'},
    'Forbidden Forest': {'Previous room': 'Destroyed Village', 'Enemy': 'Ancient Tree'}
}


# STARTING ROOM
current_room = "Town"

My script makes the player choose between options instead of typing out a response. It goes something like this:
def start_game():

    while True:

        # DISPLAY HERO INFO
        print(f"\n You are in the {current_room}.\n{'#' * 22}")

        if current_room == "Town":
            print("\nYou can either go to the NEXT ROOM or REST.")
            print("NEXT ROOM takes you to an enemy encounter.")
            print("REST fills up your HP bar.")
            print("What would you like to do?")
            print("1 - GO TO THE NEXT ROOM\n2 - REST")

            # USER INPUT
            user_input = input("> ")

            if user_input == "1":
                next_room()

            elif user_input == "2":
                pass

            else:
                print("Invalid command. Try something else.\n")

As you can see, I use the fuction "next_room()". What I'm trying to do is: the player starts in the "Town" and the "Next room", as seen in the dictionary, is the "Ruins". If the player inputs "1" to go to the next room, I would like the current_room to be updated, as the next room becomes the current room. How can I do that using the dictionary? This is what I have written so far:
def next_room():

    if "Next room" in the_map[current_room].keys():

        room_after = the_map[current_room]["Next room"]

        print(f"\nYou reached the {room_after}!")

I'm not sure of how to make it update to the current_room. It prints the statement in this code, but the first one of the original post still shows "You are in the Town" which is the starting room.

current_room = room_after - but note that you are using global variables here, so 1/ you will have to declare global current_room in the beginning of your function and 2/ your code will soon turn into some hard to manage mess. You should really try to avoid global variables as much as possible.

@ThierryLathuille that was exactly what was missing! thank you for the tip about the global variables :)

Avoid using global variables by putting the_map and current_room in start_game. Then pass variables to next_room, have it return room_after and then update with current_room = next_room(current_room, the_map).
(I also threw in an else: break since I don't know what your behavior should be afterwards.)
def start_game():
    
    the_map = {
        'Town': {'Next room': 'Ruins', 'Rest': 'Fill HP'},
        'Ruins': {'Next room': 'Destroyed Village', 'Previous room': 'Town', 'Enemy': 'Minotaur'},
        'Destroyed Village': {'Next room': 'Forbidden Forest', 'Previous room': 'The Ruins', 'Enemy': 'Giant'},
        'Forbidden Forest': {'Previous room': 'Destroyed Village', 'Enemy': 'Ancient Tree'}
    }
    
    
    # STARTING ROOM
    current_room = "Town"

    while True:

        # DISPLAY HERO INFO
        print(f"\n You are in the {current_room}.\n{'#' * 22}")

        if current_room == "Town":
            print("\nYou can either go to the NEXT ROOM or REST.")
            print("NEXT ROOM takes you to an enemy encounter.")
            print("REST fills up your HP bar.")
            print("What would you like to do?")
            print("1 - GO TO THE NEXT ROOM\n2 - REST")

            # USER INPUT
            user_input = input("> ")

            if user_input == "1":
                current_room = next_room(current_room, the_map)

            elif user_input == "2":
                pass

            else:
                print("Invalid command. Try something else.\n")
        else:
            break

def next_room(current_room, the_map):

    if "Next room" in the_map[current_room].keys():

        room_after = the_map[current_room]["Next room"]

        print(f"\nYou reached the {room_after}!")

    return room_after


That worked perfectly! I had another function called "previous_room()" which did basically the same thing as this one, and I copy-pasted the code but it gave me an error :\ Nonetheless, thank you for the help!
